# Is it possible to create an Android application where the server side run on Android Mobile?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play

I am studying the feasibility of developing a mobile application for Android, for traders, where the client-side installs on a smartphone (A) and of course, through Google Play, and server-side installs itself in another smartphone (B) that installs via the Play also.

B through the merchant takes pictures of your items and upload adding a description (this article) for the application server side, in ways that the user A, which has the side application client can enjoy the products.

In short:

1. Capturing data to the server must be made ​​through an Android phone that can take pictures of products and upload to the system and adding text to describe the product.
2. Consultation of products will be made ​​by a mobile phone with Android as well.

Is it possible to do this? If not, I would appreciate to give me suggestions on how to do this. But I wanted to try not to make using computers (PC / Mac) or web app to load the data to the application. I want a system purely mobile. Maybe will use the computers to store the BD system only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the server side is a phone app, you imply that the phone is always on, the app is always running, and you need no central storage whatsoever.

You also lose any ability to keep analytics for your service, which is a crucial part of any startup.

If you want your app to have the server available even 80% of the time, and you want to keep a central database of what's going on, you must have some server you can control.

There are a lot of very cheap and manageable cloud solutions, so you don't need to buy an actual server.

Comment: Hi Ilya,
I appreciate the clarification. But some doubt persist:
According with your explanation, I understand that server cloud solution might be the one I need. But I don't know if is good to develop one app to caputre data (photos of commercial products and its description) to installed in an Android device and automatically store it on that cloud server. Then, develop the client-side app that will be installed from Google Play, to query for these commercial information.

Comment: You can develop one app and it can have two modes: a "buyer" more and a "seller" mode. Who knows, maybe in the future sellers can also be buyers? Or you can make two different apps, but they can still share some common codebase.